# vs-code: unable to reverse search on built-in terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

When I do  `^R` on the terminal to reverse search, I get the following:

`(^R) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...`

How do I fix this? I'm on OS X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51826/ctrlr-was-pressed-waiting-for-second-key-of-chord.html) when I had your same problem. It should work for OS X since it's just about key bindings.

Answer (score 20):

Also see [Run recent command as a replacement for reverse search](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#run-recent-command-as-a-replacement-for-reverse-search) from the v1.70 Release Notes:

> When shell integration is enabled, we're aiming run recent command to
> be a cross-shell drop in replacement for the shell's reverse search
> (`kbstyle(Ctrl+R)`). There is a new contiguous search mode that is the
> default when triggering the command. This behaves like `kbstyle(Ctrl+R)`
> in most shells, with the option of switching back to fuzzy search:

[image: terminal run recent search]

> The new `inTerminalRunCommandPicker` context key is available that
> allows setting up a keybinding like `kbStyle(Ctrl+R)` to go to the next
> match. For example, the following keybindings are now a fairly
> complete replacement for your shell's reverse search, with
> `kbstyle(Ctrl+Alt+R)` as a fallback to the old behavior:

```
{ "key": "ctrl+r",     "command": "workbench.action.terminal.runRecentCommand", "when": "terminalFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+alt+r", "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence", "args": { "text": "\u0012"/*^R*/ }, "when": "terminalFocus" },
{ "key": "ctrl+r",     "command": "workbench.action.quickOpenNavigateNextInViewPicker", "when": "inQuickOpen && inTerminalRunCommandPicker" },
{ "key": "ctrl+c",     "command": "workbench.action.closeQuickOpen", "when": "inQuickOpen && inTerminalRunCommandPicker" },
```

---

Perhaps you actually want both!  Terminal keybindings that are of the form

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>something else</kbd>

that is, keybindings that are `chords` AND still use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (a non-chord keybinding) to trigger a reverse search in the terminal.

You can have both - add this keybinding to your keybindings.json:

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "\u0012" },
    "when": "terminalFocus"
  },
```

That sends a "Ctrl+R" to the terminal and thus starts a reverse search.  Even if you have other terminal keychords that starts with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, the terminal will not wait for the second part of a keybinding.

Note if you have a frequently used search you can add text to the command like:

```
    "args": { "text": "\u0012node" },
```

where it will already have started the search for commands with `node` in them.

Comment: Thank you! This is great if you want to keep CTRL+K chords enabled.

Comment: Note that on OSX in order to use `cmd` you need to change `"key": "ctrl+r",` to `"key": "cmd+r",`

Answer (score 9):

I realized that this started happening with me after I installed "Visual Studio Keymap" extension.

That is how I solved:

Ctrl + Shift + P for the command. There write: "Settings JSON" and select the option that says "Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)"

There, write the following setting:

```json
"terminal.integrated.allowChords": false
```

Save and be happy

Comment: Attention: This will disable all your chords (like the CTRL+K + ... shortcuts)

Answer (score 7):

The setting that fixed it for me:

```
"terminal.integrated.sendKeybindingsToShell": true
```

When you make a clean vscode install, there will be a popup that explains what is going on with editor and terminal shortcuts. There you can configure your settings.