# VS Code terminal history search, Windows, Powershell

Tags: powershell, search, visual-studio-code, terminal, history

since version 1.43 the `ctrl+r r` keyboard shortcut has stopped working for powershell history searches. Is there another way to search in recently used commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/70900927/836330 for how to bring up a QuickPick panel with the recent terminal commands (powershell is supported).

and

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62203544/836330 or https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_70.md#run-recent-command-as-a-replacement-for-reverse-search

---

I can't reproduce your issue.  But you could try this keybinding in the meantime:

```
{
  "key": "alt+r",
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": { "text": "\u0012" }
},
```

That sends a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to the terminal.  Focus can be anywhere.  That should trigger the reverse search of previous terminal commands.  Does it do that for you?

See related info: [Make a keybinding to run previous or last shell commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55336497/make-a-keybinding-to-run-previous-or-last-shell-commands/55336498#55336498)

Comment: Thank you, Mark. That solved my problem. I just customized it a little bit ```{ "key": "ctrl+r",                "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
                                  "args": { "text": "\u0012" },
                                  "when": "terminalFocus" },
```